# Error on submitting form ActionController::ParameterMissing in CommentsController#create param is missing or the value is empty: comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner in Rails and I have been trying to solve this issue for hours. I've searched and applied many solutions but none have worked to solve this issue.

The app is a simple blog with articles and comments. I have made them using scaffold in this project and have them nested in `routes.rb` with associations in the database.

The problem now is that the partial for the comments form is not working to add any comment at all.

The partial form for the comment:

```
 <%= form_with(url: article_comments_path) do |form| %>
  <% if comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :commenter %>
    <%= form.text_field :commenter, id: :comment_commenter %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :body %>
    <%= form.text_field :body, id: :comment_body %>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

Article model:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comments
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

Comment model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Comments controller:

```
def create
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
  #article_id = params[:article_id]
  #raise params.inspect
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_comment
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
end
```

The error I got on the form page for the comment after clicking submit:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in CommentsController#create

param is missing or the value is empty: comment Extracted source (around line #437):

#435         value
#436       else
*437         raise ParameterMissing.new(key)
#438       end
#439     end
#440 

Extracted source (around line #73):

#71     # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
#72     def comment_params
*73       params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
#74     end
#75 end

Extracted source (around line #36):

#34     
#35     @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
*36     @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
#37     redirect_to article_path(@article)
#38     
#39   end
```

routes.rb

```
               Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                       Controller#Action
         rails_admin        /admin                                            RailsAdmin::Engine
    article_comments GET    /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                     POST   /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                     PATCH  /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     PUT    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     DELETE /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            articles GET    /articles(.:format)                               articles#index
                     POST   /articles(.:format)                               articles#create
         new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                           articles#new
        edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                      articles#edit
             article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#show
                     PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                     PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                     DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#destroy
```

The server log for that action

```
Started POST "/articles/8/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-02 20:18:44 +0300
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vy35XCR5S4E7rREcavLifxAPqwzPOrl0bVbbWA4nyXgQDWFLxJYu/2YVa/NdnJGBwN7mCW8RjliPUnkGPtPwnQ==", "commenter"=>"asdasd", "body"=>"sdfdfgdf", "commit"=>"Save ", "article_id"=>"8"}
  [1m[36mArticle Load (5.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 35ms (ActiveRecord: 5.2ms)



ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: comment):

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:71:in `comment_params'
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:33:in `create'
```

*Important note:*

if I remove 
`params.require(:comment)`
the submit will pass & I will be redirected to the right page , the issue though is that it won't save the comment itself.

Please advise as I am feeling lost
Thank you all.

Comment: `param is missing or the value is empty: comment` how does your form look? and the rails server logs after sending the request to the create method?

Comment: added the form & the rails logs as requested

Comment: if I remove 
`params.require(:comment)`
the submit will pass & I will be redirected to the right page , the issue though is that it won't save the comment itself.

Comment: Instead of `Comment.new(comment_params)` try `Comment.create(comment_params)`

Comment: Either way it'll fail though, it's not associated with an article.
try `@article.comments.create(comment_params)`

Answer (score 1):

Your `form_with` isn't set up correctly. You need to build it so that it is associated with a model.

```
<%= form_with article_comments_path(Comment.new) do |form| %>
    ... parameters here... 
<% end %>
```

Will work I believe.
Here's a nice article on [Medium](https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a)

EDIT:

This should work if you're in the `Articles#Show`

```
def create
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

This will depend on how you've set up routes though.

Comment: It could also be adding an scope, instead using controller logic in the view.

Comment: Yeah I know there's a few different solutions. I'm not sure which view he's in though so it's hard to say.

Comment: Thank you , however with this setup , I get the following error (before reaching the form , in the new action) , my code above reaches the form & gives the error on create action , what do you think ?

`No route matches {:action=>"index", :article_id=>nil, :controller=>"comments"}, missing required keys: [:article_id]`

Comment: I am in the comments/new view rendering the _form for comment

Comment: Are you sure you're not in the `Articles#show` rendering the comment form partial?

Comment: I just edited my answer so that the Comments#create should associate the comment with an article

Comment: Yes , I am quite sure I am in the Comments#create , because the error is showing that controller , plus making change in the Comments#create reflect on this page that I am in

Comment: Please check the new note in the post , I noticed it can work but won't save if I remove the .require from the comment_params in the Comment controller

Comment: When you submit the form it is routed to your `Comments#create`, correct.

However, depending on how your `Articles#show` is defined, you will need to build your form a little bit differently.

If the application you're building is how I imagine it(the comment form is below the article in the `Articles#show` then the edited answer will work I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone else , *only two changes fixed the code:*

1- removing the require commment in the comment_params

```
    def comment_params
      params**.require(:comment)**.permit(:commenter, :body, :article_id)
    end
```

2- the create action didn't **have a save** after making the comment

```
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    end  
  end
```

Thanks for your help.